# Active directory user password change by ldap client

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have written a LDAP client program in C. With that I am trying to authenticate against Active Directory. I have created some users in active directory and trying authenticate with my LDAP client. Its working fine. But problem is when I create a user in AD with `user must change password at next login` option, LDAP bind function is failing. Changing password doesn't work without binding. So how can I make it work?

Comment: Did you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664482/ldap-validation-fails-when-user-must-change-password-on-next-log-on-any-solut

Comment: I am getting the same error message. But when I try to change the password, modification of attribute unicodepwd, it doesn't work. Is there any configuration need to done in Active directory server?

Comment: if the account is required to change the password, as far as I know it is not possilbe to do that as the user with ldap libraries. The only way to do it in the context of the user account is using the kerberos api. Using an administrative account you can obviously reset the password with your favourite ldap library

Comment: @natxo : I can change the password with ldap api if pswlastset attribute of user is set to other value than 0. if it set to 0 then we are unable to validate the user.